# Is there a way to specify the installation location for composer? (PSR-4)

Tags: composer-php

I'm using composer to install my package and I'm trying to install my bundle in a very specific location.

In short, I have my packages with the following namespace prefixes:

TeamXyz/AbcBundle

TeamXyz/AbcComponent

Now, since we have tons of components and bundles, we want to separate them into 2 folders like this:

vendor/TeamXyz/Component/AbcComponent

vendor/TeamXyz/Bundle/AbcBundle

It used to work very well but with PSR-4 I cannot seem to be able to control the location where my package should be installed. I wonder if I have to write custom package installer for composer to be able to do this?

Comment: Why is the *specific* location so important? As long as it goes into the vendors folder and is properly set up for composer's autoloading, it hardly matters what exactly the folder structure is.

Comment: Hi Deceze, actually you have a good point. It's just that we do share the bundles around in the team and we like to keep things organized in a certain way to work easier. And since everyone does composer update to update their packages it would be nice to be able to specify location

Comment: You are using Composer to separate the creation of packages from the consumer of packages. Then the location of packages shouldn't matter. What about changing the way you like the things to be organized instead of trying to work against the decisions made in Composer. Otherwise Composer might be the wrong tool for you, because effectively you want packages to be merged. `TeamXyz/AbcBundle` should be in `vendor/TeamXyz/Bundle/AbcBundle`, and `TeamXyz/DefBundle` should be in `vendor/TeamXyz/Bundle/DefBundle`, which is the same package from Composer perspective. Composer won't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out a way to do that, simply wrote my own custom package installer and voila.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by myTeam.
 * Date: 6/11/14
 * Time: 1:43 PM
 * Question? Come to our website at http://my.com
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace My\PackageInstaller;

use Composer\Package\PackageInterface;
use Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller;

class BundleInstaller extends LibraryInstaller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPackageBasePath(PackageInterface $package)
    {
        $prefix = substr($package->getPrettyName(), 0, 3);
        if ('my/' !== $prefix) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                'Unable to install package, my package '
                . 'should always start their package name with '
                . '"my/"'
            );
        }

        $packageName = str_replace('my/', '', $package->getPrettyName());

        return $this->vendorDir . '/my/Bundle/' . $packageName;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supports($packageType)
    {
        return 'my-bundle' === $packageType;
    }
}
```

And yes I understand everything you guys complain about, but a tool is a tool and one person can use it the best way that fits his need. At least that's what I believe :). Maybe I'm doing something stupid here for not using Composer the exact way it was meant to be used. But hey, if we are using all the tools the exact ways they were meant to be used, lots of innovation would have happened in the first place :)